# How Can I Reduce Spring Jpa Hibernate Project Deployment Time?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, tomcat, jpa

I have a web project which is develop spring, jpa and hibernate and database mysql and server Apache Tomcat 8. My project size 87 MB. and my database size 1 GB. When I run my project It take more than 20 min to deploy. I also apply Hikari Connection Pool but problem not solve. I Provide configuration file and others related file.

**This is my database.properties file**

```
################### JDBC Configuration ##########################
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

 jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306
/emdemo_liza?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=false&requireSSL=false
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=1234

################### Hibernate Configuration ##########################
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
hibernate.generate_statistics=true
hibernate.connection.charSet=UTF-8
hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider

################## For List insertion Hiber Config ######################
###hibernate.order_inserts=true###
####hibernate.order_updates=true####
```

**This is my applicationContext-db.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" 
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org
/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org
/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd">

<!-- Scan for property files -->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:META-INF/spring/*
 .properties" />

<!-- Transaction Manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<!-- Detect @Transactional -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />


<!-- Entity Manager Factory -->
 <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa
 .LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">

 <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
 <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">

        <!-- Define Hibernate JPA Vendor Adapter -->
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor
.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
    <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
</bean>
</property>
    <!-- Persistence Unit -->
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
</bean>

 <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" p:url="${jdbc.url}"
    p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />


 <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support
  .PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
 <bean id="jdbcTemplate"
   class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

**This is my entity manager class**

```
package com.netizenbd.dao.service;

import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.netizenbd.dao.EntityDao;

import javassist.bytecode.SignatureAttribute.TypeVariable;

public class EntityService<E>  implements EntityDao<E> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="persistenceUnit")
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    protected E instance;
    private Class<E> entityClass;

    @Transactional
    public void persist(E e) throws HibernateException{     
        getEntityManager().persist(e);
        getEntityManager();

    }
    @Transactional
    public void merge(E e) throws HibernateException{     
        getEntityManager().merge(e);
    }
    @Transactional
    public void remove(Object id) throws Exception{     
        getEntityManager().remove((E)getEntityManager().find(getEntityClass(), id));

    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public E findById(Object id) throws Exception {     
        return (E)getEntityManager().find(getEntityClass(), id);    
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public E findAcademicYearObj(Object id, Object year) throws Exception {     
        return (E)getEntityManager().find(getEntityClass(), id +"and"+ year);    
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<E> findAll() throws Exception{
        return getEntityManager().createQuery("Select t from " + getEntityClass().getSimpleName() + " t").getResultList();
    }
}
```

Please anybody help me how can I deploy quick within short time my project using tomcat server.

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest to analyse the log file for framework level statements viz. Spring and hibernate and identify where the largest chunk of time is consumed. (*enable `DEBUG` level logging if `INFO` logs are insufficient*) This will help narrow down on the potential causes, as currently the information shared at best is unhelpful.

Comment: Set `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to `none` you don't want hibernate to create your schema (and it takes a long time especially with `update` as it needs to detect changes). You will also need to set the `generetaDdl` property to `false`. And also use a proper connection pool (a `DriverManagerDataSource` isn't intended to be used in production like situations). If you are using component-scanning limit the amount of packages that need to be scanned.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, don't use the following property:

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

You should be using other tools to migrate your production environment's schema at deployment time such as Flyway or Liquibase rather than the Hibernate schema tooling.

Setting the property to the following should greatly improve your boot time.

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none
```

Comment: I can remove  hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update and add hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none but problem not solve

Comment: Then you need to provide more detail about where its slow and what the application is doing.